# How to load CSV files into BigQuery without creating schema

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm want to load CSV files into big query table , CSV file is creating in  real time for this type of file fixing schema is difficult .Can any one help how to load the csv files into big query using python .

I got one solution running bq command line to load csv file into bq table .
please help me how to execute bq command tools using python .
I want solutions in python how to resolve this issue 
Thanks in advance

Comment: what you mean "fixing a schema is difficult"? does data in your csv files change schema over time?

Comment: @Will yes data is the csv files changes over the time

Answer (score 1):

If you use bq method in Google Cloud try:

```
bq \
--project_id your_project_id_from_gcp \
--location=US \                                   
load \
--autodetect \                                    
--ignore_unknown_values \
--source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON \          
'table_name.examplev1' \                         
/Users/.../file.json
```

This example is using json file, bq works with csv too and other formats, you just have to change 'source_format' and your 'file'.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Schema Autodetect? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect